# In excel how can I sum all the cells above the current cell upto a particular cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

What formula should I apply to add all the cells above the current cell but only up to a cell with a particular text.

Like in case of the below example the formula adds all cells above it but only up to "Amount", not above that, so that if cells are inserted in between they get added too.

**Amount**

1000

500

345

560

Formula

Comment: Are you giving us the full scenario? If you can see the cell with `Amount`, just start the sum one cell below. If it is more complex than that, please edit your question and provide the missing details.

Comment: The starting point is trivial, just specify it.  Adding rows will be accommodated as long as they are within your range.  If you add above or below the range endpoints, you will need provisions to handle that.  Can you clarify the requirements better?

Answer (score 1):

If the cell with the text `Amount` is in A1, you can use

=sum($A$2:a5)

If a row is inserted between rows 2 and 5, then the formula will update to

=sum($A$2:a6)

If, however, you add a new row above row 6, the formula will not change. In that case you man want to have a blank row above the formula. Include the blank row in the sum formula. When you want to insert a new row, select the blank row and insert the row, then the formula will update.

Or, you can save all that hassle and use an Excel Table object (Insert ribbon > Table) turn on table totals, then you don't have to write a formula at all. To enter a new row at the bottom of the table, select the last cell in the last row and hit the Tab key.

You can also create the formula manually if you need it outside the table, like this.

```
=sum(Table1[amount])
```

Comment: +1 for table, the simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is a little clunky, so there is probably a way to optimize, but try this.

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("$A"&MATCH("Amount",$A:A,0)+1&":$A$"&ROW()-1))
```

[image]

Comment: I was going to post almost the identical answer until I realized that even that isn't bulletproof.  There could be multiple ranges, with "Amount" appearing more than once.  The formula could get insane coping with every possibility.  Figured it made sense to just ask the OP what requirements they needed to handle.  :-)

Comment: Please, not Indirect. This can be done non-volatile,